# Using Glassfish + GWT in development mode

Tags: gwt, glassfish, ejb

Okey so this is how im currently working:

1. Im using EJBs (3.x) for my service layer
2. Im using GWT for my visual layer
3. Im comunication GWT with EJBs with debendency injection (@EJB annotation)

So the problem is that im woking kind of slow because whenever i make a small change to my GWT layer I have to compile wich takes some time. 
I was wondering if there was a way to work with Glassfish + GWT + EJBs in production mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you should do following things:
1. Deploy ejb only on Glassfish (for development mode). It's no point to build full ear when you want web part in development mode.
2. Use remote interfaces (we're using service locator that detects whether it should work on local or remote interfaces for EJBs).
3. Add gf-client.jar to bootstrap entries of GWT development mode (while launching from eclipse).
4. Add ejb client jar to classpath entries of GWT dev mode.

Setup like this will save you time consuming recompilations when you change something on the GWT site (you just hit reload button and it works with new code). When you change something on the ejb's side you still have to close dev mode, redeploy ejb and launch dev mode again, to make it work.

It's not very straightforward setup but it works. We're using maven profiles to produce ejb only build for development and full ear for production.

There's also noserver mode that will be a little bit simpler (it will connect to web part deployed on glassfish, not jetty) but it's less productive, because each change on GWT RPC side requires time-consuming recompilation and redeploy of war (or full ear).

Comment: ok i dont understand step 3 very well. Where do I find gf-client.jar? and what are the bootstrap entires? is it the WEB-INF? what is the client jar? im sorry if these questions are to noobish, im kinda new to all of this

Comment: gf-client.jar can be found in <GLASSFISH_HOME>/glassfish/lib directory. You should modify eclipse run configuration for development mode to include this library.

Comment: Ok, i found out what the bootstrap is, I added the gf-client.jar but I cant seem to find the ejb client jars... Do you know where I can find them.  (I found some folders named exactly like my ejb project's name inside the glassfish dir)

Comment: You can use full jar generated from build of ejb module. It will contain more classes than client only, but should also work. I'm generating client libraries with maven ejb plugin, but there should be also an option to do that from "pure" eclipse projects as well as from appserver tools.

Comment: Works for me when using JNDI lookups for the EJBs, but has anyone ever gotten this work with @EJB dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

in that case you don't need to deploy service layer. 
You could work with hosted mode to see changes on GWT side.

http://code.google.com/eclipse/

with google plug-in you run in eclipse and see changes only page refresh.
Jetty is a server in eclipse to develop GWT based web applications.

Comment: im not sure what you mean, im already using the eclipse plugin

Comment: sorry this reply is a quick send post :)
jgrabowski explained the process which I meant